# How did docker daemon limit container's disk bandwidth like docker run --device-read-bps

Tags: docker, kubernetes

We can limit container's disk bandwidth when create it by using `docker run --device-read-bps`. Actually I'm using kubernetes to create container. Want make every container in my node use only 50M/s disk bandwidth .
Is there any way can configure docker daemon like `docker run --device-read-bps`?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes supports CPU and Memory limits, but as far as I know, it does not handle any disk quota or limits at this time.

In PersistentVolumes, you can specify StorageClass, but that only seems to imply slow or fast disk (i.e. HD or SSD..) and that does not have any bandwidth limitation.

So in short I do not think it is possible.

Comment: U are right, k8s didn't support disk bandwidth limit.So I want to use not k8s but docker to control it. I know "docker run " has a parameter "--device-read-bps" can control the container's disk bandwidth. However I don't know how to add it to "docker daemon".Tks!

Comment: In fact, I want every container has the same disk bandwidth limit. I'm worry  about that if I didn't control it one container may exhaust all of my node's disk resource.

Comment: from the docker commnad , it is only possible at run time. there doesn't seem to be such global parameter for the daemon